# External scripts not loading dynamically in angular 5

Tags: angular, dynamic, angular-cli, angular5, external-script

I have included the external scripts in .angular-cli.json file in the scripts property i.e.

`

```
"scripts": [
      "../src/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js",
      "../src/assets/plugins/popper/popper.min.js",
      "../src/assets/plugins/jquery-blockui/jquery.blockui.min.js",
      "../src/assets/plugins/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js",
      "../src/assets/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js",
      "../src/assets/plugins/datatables/plugins/bootstrap/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js",
      "../src/assets/js/pages/table/table_data.js",
      "../src/assets/js/app.js",
      "../src/assets/js/layout.js",
      "../src/assets/js/theme-color.js",
      "../src/assets/plugins/material/material.min.js",
      "../src/assets/js/pages/ui/animations.js",
      "../src/assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js",
      "../src/assets/plugins/bootstrap-inputmask/bootstrap-inputmask.min.js",
      "../src/assets/plugins/bootstrap-datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js",
      "../src/assets/plugins/bootstrap-datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker-init.js",
      "../src/assets/plugins/jquery-tags-input/jquery-tags-input.js",
      "../src/assets/plugins/jquery-tags-input/jquery-tags-input-init.js",
    ],`
```

when the angular app is started, all the scripts are loaded. but when I switch to another page, the scripts do not load.

Answer (score 0):

Angular is for single page apps, technically you'll never switch a page when in an ng app, as long as you use the router correctly. All scripts get bundled together, added to index.html by Webpack and only ever loaded once when index.html is loaded.

Comment: yes I can understand your point, what I mean is when the app is first loaded and is on index route i.e. '/' all the scripts are loaded for example datatable script. But when I switch to another page lets say '/page2', the page contents load dynamically, but the scripts do not.

Comment: That's how a SPA works: Scripts are only loaded once. If you're trying to execute some external JS on every router navigation, it can't be done this way. You should dive deeper into Angular and learn try to do everything inside Angular instead.

Comment: if that is the case then how come scripts are not loading on navigation? I'm saying that scripts are loaded initially but when I change the route, it disappear.

Comment: What disappear? The scripts don't go anywhere, they're just loaded only once and executed only once - when the app initializes, like they're supposed to.

Comment: I want them to be loaded for every route when I click to another route as one of my pages has datatables which require script.

Comment: You cannot if you want to use angular. You need to figure out an angular way to do it. It would be best to forget jQuery alltogether. Google around, you'll find better ways to do it. Use Angular HttpClient to load any dynamic data you may need.

Comment: Trust me, if you take the time to really learn what angular is about and forget the "old way" of doing things, and start to think the angular way, you won't regret it later. :)

Comment: So, if you bought a HTML/CSS/JS theme, you can't use it in you Angular App because it is not done for Angular ?

Comment: I have a static site running in production that I need to migrate to Angular, but I want to keep using the theme... And I can't because Angular can't deal with a simple jquery theme.